# Matricial form of the killing form of $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was reading some of my old notes and I found an explicit matricial form for the killing form
$$
\left(\kappa_{ij}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
4n\\
 & \ddots\\
 &  & 4n\\
 &  &  & 0 & 2n\\
 &  &  & 2n & 0\\
 &  &  &  &  & \ddots\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & 0 & 2n\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & 2n & 0
\end{array}\right),
$$
where the number of $4n$ equals the dimension of the cartan sub-algebra. I'm wondering if there are other explicit form for the killing form and why I don't see them written in every textbook if there are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bourbaki's *Lie groups and Lie algebras* contains, at the end of the 8<sup>th</sup> chapter, a table concerning the classical Lie algebras (the four families $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$, and $D_n$), wich contains explicit descriptions of the restriction (as a bilinear form) of the Killing form to a Cartan subalgebra.